# Attribute Error: 'unicode' object has no attribute 'extent'

Tags: arcpy, arcmap, vector, vector-grid

I keep getting this error from this line.

```
arcpy.CreateFishnet_management(os.path.join(Output_Folder, "Full_Grid.shp"), str(NAR_U9.extent.XMin) + " " + str(NAR_U9.extent.YMin), str(NAR_U9.extent.XMin) + " " + str(NAR_U9.extent.YMin + 10), Cell_Size_Width, Cell_Size_Height, "0", "0", str(NAR_U9.extent.XMax) + " " + str(NAR_U9.extent.YMax), "NO_LABELS", NAR_U9, "POLYLINE")
```

I can't seem to find anything online about what the 'unicode' part means. I'm giving it specific values for the coordinates for the corners so I don't understand where it's looking for an extent attribute.

Comment: Looking at ESRIs tool reference for CreateFishnet, I notice the datatype for the extent template is 'extent'. I have it as NAR_U9 which is a variable referenced to a shapefile. Shouldn't this work?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Extent is accessed with [Describe](http://desktop.arcgis.com/en/arcmap/10.3/analyze/arcpy-functions/describe.htm) and the [Extent function](http://desktop.arcgis.com/en/arcmap/10.3/analyze/arcpy-functions/dataset-properties.htm), for example:

```
import arcpy
fc = r'C:\path\file.shp'
desc = arcpy.Describe(fc)
xmin = desc.extent.XMin
```